# How to get 'current location only' in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, core-location

I am using Core Location framework to getting location in iOS. I use, `CLLocationManager *locationManager;` and call `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

Problem is I only need instantaneous location but `startUpdatingLocation` keep on giving me location.  To stop this I can use `[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]`, but this look like a way out or hack.

Is there any better way to just get current location in iOS?

Comment: No, its not a hack. This is the proper way to get location information

Comment: You can't get location instantaneously!  It does not work that way.  You need to get multiple updates.  CL starts by giving you a cached value which may be old (hours possibly).  CL then gives you low accuracy values while it tries to get higher accuracy.  You need to deal with this, that is the way it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it

```
-(void)getCurrentLocation
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    startLocation = nil;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (startLocation == nil)
    {
        startLocation = newLocation;
        [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
        locationManager = nil;

    }
}
```

Comment: -1: This is a bad way to get current location.  The first value returned by the location manager is usually a *cached* location, **NOT** a real location.  This code doesn't call `stopUpdatingLocation` after setting the delegate to nil, it will run down the battery.

Comment: Are  you sure @progrmr ? I have tested it on my device and have been using since last 1 year . No battery drain and nothing

Comment: Absolutely.  The only thing saving your battery is the auto pause they added in iOS 6 and the fact your app doesn't run in background. You start location manager with `startUpdatingLocation` and you *should* always call `stopUpdatingLocation` when you are done with it.

Answer (score 2):

in your .h file

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

 @interface LocationSearchViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
 {
 CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

in your .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];


locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];   // when u got the lat and long it stop uoatde the location

CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {

  NSString  *getcurrlong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
  NSSting *getcurrlat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];



}
}
```

Comment: Your code is perfect. But my problem is `(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` will be called many times to update location. I just needed current location.

Comment: i called [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; in the delegate method, so it will work at only one time, i also used in the current project on the above code ,it working fine for me

Comment: Sorry. Other answer bit more cleaner.  Concept is same.

Comment: tanx bro, doest not the matter, happy day

Answer (score 2):

You can't think of location in those precise terms. You'll get back increasingly accurate locations from the location manager and it's up to you to decide when it's accurate enough. You have to weigh this against power usage and time. The location updates will never be completely accurate. The will never be returned immediately. The device has to power up hardware, then listen for GPS/WiFi/Cell signals and use all those to calculate location.

There's no way to ask for "my precise current location" and have it given to you immediately. Location is not a property like `[NSDate date]`. You can only ask for best-estimate location updates and they will only come to you in imprecise measurements, and never instantaneously (excepting cached location).